# How do I add padding to a UIButton using the xcode interface builder?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm using a 32 point icon as a button and I'm trying to increase the tappable area to 44 points to meet Apple's guidelines. Can I do this using the interface building instead of code? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Just use the height you want in your button (44x44, per instance) and set the icon as image, not as background.

[image]

Comment: Grt thanks man! I never thought about it   . Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constraint view in the right corner:

[image: Constraint View]